# Simple hive select not giving full results

Tags: sql, hive, locks

I'm querying a table, let's call it 'customer_table', this has partitions by day in 'yyyymmdd' format.
When looking at the partitions with `'show partitions customer_table'` I can see there is data for yesterday and the day before.
However, when I run a query like :

```
'select customer, customer_joined_date, name, address, city
from customer_table ct
left join addresses addr on ct.cust_id=addr.cust_id
where ct.customer_joined_date >= date_format(date_sub(current_date,7),'yyyyMMdd')
```

This query is not including the data from yesterday or previous day.
My instinct is the previous 2 days partitions have some kind of lock which prevents querying while data is still streaming into them.

Can you suggest what's happening? Is there an environment parameter which i can set so the query ignores 'locks'?

Comment: `show partitions` gives you just partitions which are folders in HDFS per se, even though those folder are empty `show partitions` will output something. Check out with `select * from your_table limit 10`

Answer (score 0):

Could you do the query below just to check that there’s no funky stuff going on in the join-

```
  select max(customer_joined_date)
  from customer_table ct
  Where ct.customer_joined_date >= date_format(date_sub(current_date,7),'yyyyMMdd');
```

If you still don’t see the data from latest partitions, you can try doing gather stats for the latest partitions once and see if that results in any chance.Below is an example of the syntax.

```
 ANALYZE TABLE Table1 PARTITION(ds='2008-04-09') COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```